# On my build server I only get Stubs and not Moles

Tags: .net, tfs, mstest, moles

We are using Moles to test some of our legacy code.  Currently all of our unit tests pass when run locally using either MSTest or Resharper's test runner.  However when run on the build server (we use a slightly modified TFS 2010 Workflow, using MSBuild and MSTest) all of our Moles tests fail.

When I looked into the cause it was because when the .Moles.dll were generated on the build server, only the Stubs (classes prefixed with "S") were created but none of the Moles classes (classes prefixed by "M").

Our code still compiles because one of our developers created a Framework for Moles to simplify the syntax, which uses Expressions and Delegates to make working with Moles feel like working with Moq.  The framework uses Reflection to get the Moles version of the methods but because the "M" classes are created it throws a NullReferenceException when trying to get the method because the call to Assembly.GetType returns null.

EDIT: The latest version of the Pex & Moles library are installed on the build server.

EDIT 2: Here is the command line that is in the MSBuild Log

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Moles\bin\moles.exe" @"D:\Builds\4\DeltaNet\Run All Unit Tests\Sources\DeltaNet\src\DeltaNetTests\obj\Debug\Moles\moles.args"
```

And the contents of "moles.args"

```
Common.Logging.moles;DeltaNetUtils.moles;System.configuration.moles /molesfilesonly /referenceassemblies:"<lots-of-dll-files>" /cachepath:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Moles\bin\..\MolesAssemblies" /intermediatepath:"D:\Builds\4\DeltaNet\Run All Unit Tests\Sources\DeltaNet\src\DeltaNetTests\obj\Debug\Moles" /outputpath:"D:\Builds\4\DeltaNet\Run All Unit Tests\Sources\DeltaNet\src\DeltaNetTests\MolesAssemblies" /clrversion:v4.0.30319 /targetframeworkversion:v4.0
```

Comment: Aren't the M prefix classes built on installation of Moles.  Maybe you need to install in the TFS build server,

Comment: It is installed, but also, I am talking about the Moles version of our Classes not the standard .net classes

Comment: I haven't integrated Moles with our TFS Build server yet ( still evaluating framework ) but it appears that the Moles assembly generating is not integrated into the build process.  I think the xxx.Moles generating is a manual step performed by right-clicking on the solution and re-running the .mole generation.  There is a MolesAssembly folder that is not included in the project so if it isn't check into TFS then they will not be available at runtime.  Are you getting TFS build warnings about missing xxxx.Moles assembly references in solution/project builds ?

Comment: Are you issuing a command to compile Moles? If so, please post it.

Comment: Not directly, I just call MSBuild which calls it.  It uses the same Solution file on dev and the build server so it should use the same arguments.

Comment: @MikeChristian I added the command MSBuild is issuing to Moles to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I had another look at this today and I think I came up with the problem and it was depressingly simple.

I was using moles in 2 different test projects and in one of them I specified exactly which classes I wanted the moles for using the `assembly.moles` xml file.  This one must have been compiled after the one with the bulk of my tests and so it overwrote it in the Binaries directory.

I removed the specifics from that file and now it looks like my tests are passing and the MXXX types are being created.